# Simple file reading from Drive using new Drive API

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

My app needs to read certain files that may be located on the local file system or from cloud services such as Dropbox and Drive. The new Drive API seems to have complicated things greatly compared to what used to work, and I am having trouble finding a full example that works the way I expect it to work.

My app does not do any "file management" on the cloud services, but expects to get an Intent when a file is selected in the cloud app itself, i.e., the user runs the Drive app, finds their file, and taps to select it (and launch my app to handle it). When a file is selected in this way, Drive broadcasts an Intent for an app to handle the file. From what I've found, I believe that the intent filter in my app should look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</intent-filter>
```

Taking it from there is where I'm getting lost, not only in the actual accessing of the file, but also in what is meant by "connecting and authorizing" in the documentation. Are there any examples of an app that operates like this? Again, all I need to do is to read the contents of the selected file and copy it to my private file storage for local access.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the samples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/)? The android-demos seem seems to have an Intent sample similar to what you're suggesting. With that you can modify it to the case you want.

Comment: Yes, I did just start examining those samples. I expect I'll get it with some trial and error.

Comment: I used the "Intent Intercept" app to see what Drive is actually sending for an Intent. Not what I was expecting, but at least I have something to start with to get the uri, etc.